# Exposing Alcohol in films to kids or teens

Tags: short-films, legal

Are you allowed to show kids or teens drinking alcoholic drinks in short films? Or is it against the law in the UK?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is the right site for this question.  We are enthusiasts and experts on the subject of movies and TV - not necessarily experts at law, in the UK or elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have a reason to think this would not be allowed? Seems like they do it all the time... particularly since the drinking age in the UK is 16 for some beverages (with restrictions) and 18 for others.

Comment: There are extremely strong rules in the UK against alcohol advertising banning their targeting at children or placement against content that is likely to attract an audience under 18 years.  I'm not aware of any rule banning the showing of under-age people drinking alcohol - after all this would seen to be a restriction on free speech - for instance if it were a documentary.  If such a movie were glamorizing alcohol use and targeting a young audience there might be significant outcry, but I'm not sure it would be illegal.

Comment: But none of the above is legal advice.  Seriously - I don't know what the nature of your question is, but we're movie enthusiasts, not lawyers.

Comment: If there were one, this might be more suitable for a film production site... it **might** be acceptable on [video.se] but I'm not familiar enough with their scope. When I had the filmmaking proposal (which died) it was implied in a discussion that production questions are welcome there... but it doesn't seem like much of a fit to me.

Comment: I asked because one of the scenes in my film shows a teen who is depressed and drinks alcohol :)

Comment: http://mobile.reuters.com/article/idUSKBN0N725V20150416 answer is here